# SharePoint notification

Tags: sharepoint-server, caml-query

I am trying to make a dynamic notification field which shows the number of for example not approved items in a list. But this needs to be shown always, wherever I am in SP.

It should look like:

- Home
- Documents
- List A
- List B (3)

[image]

List B has 3 items that match my requirements. Has anyone any experience with this? Is the using of caml query necessary?

SP Server 2013

Comment: Exactly how should the notification begin made available "everywhere"? Judging by you question, you need a modification that updates the list name everywhere it appears on the site. This would include heterogeneous components like the Quick Launch, the site global navigation, pages that list content on the site (like the All Site Content one) and so on. But... your comments also talk about using a web part and "placing it on the sites you need the notification on". I am pretty confused now. Can you please describe the use-case you have in mind in a little more detail?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to keep it short and clear. Yes, I wanted to modify the master page (quick launch) or add content webparts to all the lists which I use. I succeed and found a solution. I made a list with one item which has a column for the counter. In the list where it is counting the items I made a workflow which updates that one list item with the counter. Then I used js including this lines:

var ListItem = myList.getItemById(1);  
var userId = ListItem.get_item('Counter');
document.getElementById("counterText").innerHTML = userId;

It refreshes on window load.

Comment: So now you have the original list, a secondary list update via a workflow that stores the information you need and a custom JavaScript function that updates a **specific** tag in the page with the desired content. Even assuming that both the script and the custom tag end up in every page by using a custom action (which still won't solve another problem - how to place the tag in the right place), I still don't get why you couldn't update the display name of your original list in the workflow instead. Probably I am failing to see some part of your requirements, sorry.

Comment: I placed it on the right place with `css` and fixed position. I didn't know that I could update a list name with a workflow. But here are some screenshots of the structure:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/LGb2g.png  http://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xl3F.png

It shows that on both lists the counter is on the right places. PS: it counts the "Nein" in the "Verarbeitet" column.

Comment: @Senad, can you share the steps you did in a step-by-step guide? I would love to try that myself. I am also from germany so maybe we can talk / mail sometimes?

Comment: @Patrick, leave me your email and Ill contact you so we can talk about it.

Comment: patrick@afrait.com

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem feasible without some tricks with the exact requirements you define. Since SharePoint will use the display name as the list label, to have the list use the custom name format "everywhere2, you would need the SPList instance to actually return its display name as "list_name (#)". I don't see any easy way to achieve this.

Excluding solutions that would require you to customize all the components that will ever show the list of lists available on the site to support your custom logic (for example: the quick launch navigation, the site breadcrumb, the "all site contents" view...), your best bet would be to actually update the display name of the list real-time to include the missing information.

I don't know your infrastructure enough to provide an exact solution, but as a starting point you could look at list event handlers. The idea would be to update the list display name whenever an item is updated/inserted/deleted to reflect the actual number of item still requiring approval (notice that if you have workflows running, you may need to update them also). Since the actual list name would include the number of pending item, it would be displayed everywhere without requiring further customization.

Comment: I was searching about this problem a lot today. I found a way which could maybe work. I plan to make a help list with only 1 item which has a column with the sum of those fields that I need. Then I tried with a content editor and some scripts to get the value of that item with the command `SP.ListItem.get_item ()`. Well, it works somehow but it's still not finished. If someone could give a advice how to combine all this. Thanks

Comment: @senad - the main problem I see is that your requirement ask for the notification to be shown "everywhere". Correct me if I misinterpreted what you need, but to me this read as "everywhere the name of the list is shown, you have to integrate the name with the notification number". The problem I see is that nothing is stopping SharePoint from just using the name of the list with no addition somewhere, and I don't see a way to bypass this behavior by basically replacing the "get list name" logic. With those premises, the only solution I can see is to have the name of the list include the info.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Yes, it should be shown everywhere, but it is okay that i use always the same listname in the getlistname logic. I always need to see the information from that one list. In the end I would copy that webpart to each site that I want to have this notification. I am not the best at javascript so I currently don't know how to write the whole code. Is here any advice? Btw the information doesn't need to update in real time when there is really a change, it can refresh just per window load.